# Google DFP: Pass UTM_Source to DFP with javascript (without accessing the DFP Admin)

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-dfp

I'm looking for a way to grab the utm_source value from a URL with javascript and pass it to Google DFP, which doesn't involve configuring anything in the DFP Admin (such as key-value targeting) as we don't have access to the admin panel for the specific site we are working with.

Would appreciate any tips / javascript code.

Comment: On Stackoverflow, we appreciate that you show some effort of code so we, the community, can expand upon the code and help you to advance.

Comment: @narusin - what makes you think this is homework? Why would a student be grabbing utm_source from URL to pass on to DFP - that's a lot of TLA's, LOL

Comment: Let me rephrase my wording.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTargetting. You will need to access the Inventory  tab in DFP's dashboard to create the utm code keys ([Key-values link](https://www.google.com/dfp/#inventory/customTargeting))

```
<script>

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    googletag.cmd.push(function () {
        googletag.pubads().setTargeting('utm_source', getParameterByName('utm_source'));
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I am having quite similar issue, I set the targeting but I am not sure what should I set in the ad manager config should I set only the key and leave value empty if I want to set it as the value I get from the URL?
also do you have report example where can I get the value by impressions/clicks?