# Find the Revenue Earned for a Pageview on DFP by using utms

Tags: key-value, google-dfp, utm

So far I've been using utms to traffic the amount of traffic I'm getting from a particular source. However, I'd like to take this a step further and track the revenue earned from this source by using utms in DFP.

Is that possible? If so, how? I think you're supposed to be using Key-Value pairs in DFP reporting. But what should be the key and what should be the value? How do you target to the line items?

I've been referencing to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dfp/JqPmCsh4jc8;context-place=topicsearchin/dfp/category$3Aaudience%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) article but I still don't know how to do it.

What's the step by step procedure?

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Preet Rajdeo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you want its only possible with DFP Premium + Google Analytics 360.

The [docs](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/188092?hl=en&ref_topic=1638397) says that key-values is for targeting purposes, but if you have DFP Premium you can also try something about Partners & Partner Assignments (its under Companies in the Admin tab) and use key-values with utms code when creating new assignments. You can check this link about how to pass utm codes to DFP:
[Google DFP: Pass UTM_Source to DFP with javascript (without accessing the DFP Admin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507594/google-dfp-pass-utm-source-to-dfp-with-javascript-without-accessing-the-dfp-ad/44165869#44165869)

But, if you don't have a DFP Premium account maybe the Reach report could help you.

Comment: What do you mean by the reach report? @felipk

Comment: Reach report is a report to determine Unique visitors - Average revenue/visitor - Average impressions/ visitor. More info: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2672504?hl=en&ref_topic=6136880