# Add URL parameters to DoubleClick destination URL

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

1. Is there anyway to add URL Parameters to the destination URL of a creative?

Example:

I load a banner on the website that has the destination link in DFP www.mysite.com

The javascript on the page forces DFP to add zone=above_the_fold

When the user clicks the banner the destination link is now www.mysite.com?zone=above_the_fold

2. If somehow the above is possible, can I mix parameters from DFP with forced parameters from javascript code?

Example:
I load a banner on the website that has the destination link in DFP www.mysite.com?campaign=summer_sale

The javascript on the page forces DFP to add zone=above_the_fold

When the user clicks the banner the destination link is now www.mysite.com?campaign=summer_sale&zone=above_the_fold

Note: Due to a very very specific business case I use DFP to advertise to pages on the same website and I need to measure the impact on sales in Google Analytics. That's what the parameters are for.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First you need to pass the URL parameters to DFP. You can try [Google DFP: Pass UTM_Source to DFP with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507594/google-dfp-pass-utm-source-to-dfp-with-javascript-without-accessing-the-dfp-ad/44165869#44165869)

After that, you will build the destination URL:

```
<script>
    var clickTag = %%CLICK_URL_ESC%%%%DEST_URL%%?=utm_source=%%PATTERN:utm_source%%;
</script>
```

%%PATTERN:utm_source%% it is a [DFP Macro](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2376981?hl=en)

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much.  Do you know if I can pass this in a DFP tag, or macros are supported only for  custom/third party tags?

Comment: Macros can be included in any code that's processed by the ad server during the delivery process: third-party or custom creative code, DoubleClick Rich Media code, click-through URLs, or DFP tags.